# How to remove specific XML tag and empty parent tags using Groovy?

Tags: xml, groovy

I'd like to remove the tag containing this exact number '123456789' and its parent tags from the XML document using Groovy. How would I do this?

> ```
>    <CdtrAcct>
>       <Id>
>         <Othr>
>           <Id>123456789</Id>
>         </Othr>
>       </Id>
>     </CdtrAcct>
> ```

Expecting the removal of this specific tag and its empty parent tags

Answer (score 0):

Transformimg Xml can be done by xslt.
See [this url](https://community.boomi.com/s/article/howtousexslttotransformxmldocumentsusinggroovy) on how to use Xslt with groovy

The xslt you would need for your question looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
  
  <!--  xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" means copy everything that does not matches a template rule -->
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <!--  this match on the CdtrAcct[Id/Othr/Id/text()='123456789'] will catch your rule and because there is no output, the whole structure will be skipped -->
  <xsl:template match="CdtrAcct[Id/Othr/Id/text()='123456789']"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[The latest versions of Saxon-HE for Java can be found here.](https://www.saxonica.com/download/java.xml)